# Type Casting problem with same copied values to new array type

Tags: c++, algorithm, casting

Im facing a serious problem and I need your help please!
what Im facing is that Im getting value from another function as integer
which they are : `{5,1,2,3,4,5}`
so those value exactly I want to copy them to an array type `uint8_t`.
this means the array that I want to get is

```
uint8_t arr={5,1,2,3,4,5};
```

what actually the problem?
the problem is this if I want to initialize and array type uint8_t with those values then I write immediately in the compiler:
`uint8_t arr={5,1,2,4,5}` (I mean by intilizing immediately ..once I write my syntax uint8_t arr in my compiler I write immediately [code]`{5,1,2,3,4,5}`[/code] )
the problem that those values I'm getting them from other function ..and I want those values to be entered as it's in an array type `uint8_t` this means my array would be the same with those value but type `uint8_t => uint8_t arr={5,1,2,3,4,5};`

how can I do that ? I tried to use unsigned int and starting filling it with values  `{5,1,2,3,4,5}`  but it didn't work!

any help how can I implement that? thanks a lot.

what I tried by code is this:

```
int array2={5,1,2,3,4,5};
unit8_t array1[6]={0};
for(int i=0;i<(sizeof(array2)/sizeof(array2[0]));i++)
{
array1[i]=array2[i];} /*I want the same values of array2 to enter to array1 but the type of array to be uint8_t*/
}
 for(int i=0;i<6;i++)
    {
cout<<array2[i];
    }
}
```

so what I expect to get once I print output is the array1 which it should be : [code] {5,1,2,3,4,5} and array1 type uint8_t with the same values that I copied them to it.

but the output is wrong answer, it's ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½aï¿½ï¿½ß™ï¿½ï¿½Iï¿½ï¿½

my purpose is to get an array type `uint8_t` with the same values copied, this means my output is an array like this `uint8_t array1={5,1,2,3,4,5}` , same values with type `uint8_t`.

Comment: You don't show the code you're using to perform the output, and the error is almost surely in that code, not the code you've shown.

Comment: I edited and updated ! , I want to get the same values on the array type uint8_t

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you want to do with your array1, But if you just want result on output screen then you have to convert it into integer value first before pushing it into stream to see the values i.e

```
int array2[] = {5,1,2,3,4,5};
uint8_t array1[6];
for(int i=0;i<6;i++)
{
    array1[i]= (array2[i]); 
}
for(int i=0; i<6; i++){
    cout << int(array1[i]) << ' ';  //This line here
}
```

Comment: That would be because, it treats it as a char type value. Values are correct but you wont be able to understand them that;s why you must be seeing weird characters on output screen

Answer (score 0):

You are just printing it wrong, likely as chars, print using formatting instead:

```
typedef unsigned char uint8_t;

#include<iostream>


    template <typename T, unsigned  N>
    constexpr unsigned countof(T const (&)[N]) noexcept
    {
    return N;
    }

int main()
{
int array2[]={5,1,2,3,4,5};
uint8_t array1[countof(array2)];
for(int i=0;i<countof(array2);i++)
{
array1[i]=array2[i];
}

for(auto x : array1)
{
printf("%u", x);
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: it still not working , it shows me this: main.cpp:32:32: error: parameter declared ‘auto’
     template <typename T, auto N>
                                ^
main.cpp:33:44: error: ‘countof’ function uses ‘auto’ type specifier without trailing return type
     constexpr auto countof(T const (&)[N]) noexcept

Comment: Try now. Fixe dit

Comment: Hi ! it works fine! thanks alot, but I dont want to just copy it ! I understand it and I didn't understand why you're using Template and what they are about? I have never used Template in my programming -Im still newbie-, could you please explain to me what template are in c++? and why you used them in this case? really appreciated if you could elaborate in simple words

Comment: Just some improvement ideas: `countof` is equivelant to `std::size` and `uint8_t` should be included from header `cstdint`, makes life easier :)

Comment: @churill Precisely. Use std::uint8_t and std::size_t.

Comment: @DavidToy countof is just a really useful function you should have. It decides the size of the array at compile time( before the program ever runs) by reading the array declaration, this can be done with so-called templates which are a way to capture generic behaviours in the language. My formatting is awful, I am on mobile so cant fix it. Ill leave that as an exercise. The only way to learn what templates are is to use them. It will come later, dont focus on that now.

Answer (score 0):

Compare your code with this

```
#include <stdint.h>
int main(void)
{
    int     array_int[6] =  { 5,1,2,3,4,5 };
    uint8_t array_byte[6] = { 0 };
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(array_byte); i+=1)
        array_byte[i] = (uint8_t) array_int[i];
    return;
 };
```

Maybe you typed here directly and not from a code you compiled before. You must use **sizeof()** the array of bytes, or use **sizeof(array_int)/sizeof(int)** to control the loop.
The cast **(uint8_t) array_int** is just for clarity and can be omitted.

Comment: my question is this, now lets assume I have write immediately in my compiler this                                unit8_t array_byte={5,1,2,3,4,5} , is that the same as the code that you write? I mean the same copied values but the array type is uint8_t?

Comment: the problem that if I write input to my function immediately on the compiler the input           uint8_t array_byte={ 5,1,2,3,4,5 }; it gives me an output .. but if I input to the same function an input but the array is a copied array type uint8_t (as what you coded above) it gives me different output! really weird!

Comment: at the end implicitly the two inputs are valued the same values, but one is a copied values and the other input is type uint8_t immediate input that I enter its values immediately on the compiler and gets different outputs with the same values of inputs and the two inputs type uint8_t but one is immediate and other is copied array(like what you coded above)

Comment: It is the same thing. Maybe you could post the code giving different values so I can tell you where the problem is. It is not here in the assignment